# How to use google photo_reference in img src without exposing my key in url?

Tags: node.js, google-maps, google-api, google-places-api, google-photos

I'm  using google place API to fetch the google photo reference and I already got that and I used it like
`https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/photo?maxwidth=400&photoreference=PHOTOREFHERE&key=YOUR_API_KEY`

And it's working fine in img tag, but the problem lies where the img tag src is exposing my key into URL

Does anyone have any idea how can I use the google place photo URL without exposing my key ?

Comment: [Restrict your API key](https://developers.google.com/maps/api-security-best-practices).

Comment: Duplicate of [How do I securely use Google API Keys](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39625587/how-do-i-securely-use-google-api-keys)

Answer (score 0):

There are really two options:

1. Restrict API key, enable only the Places API, Adjust quota for API to match expected usage. Use key on frontend.
2. Proxy the requests (see https://stackoverflow.com/a/63618936/3145360) and optionally restrict API key with server IP